# Desktop Safari and iOS HTML audio tag error with wav files - 206 Partial Content

Tags: ios, reactjs, amazon-web-services, audio, safari

In the project I'm working right now we need to load multiple audio .WAV files. Everything works fine with Chrome and Firefox, on mobile devices and desktop.

The problem comes with any browser on iOS and Safari on Desktop. It shows the word Error on the audio control on Mobile, and in Desktop Safari says 206 Partial Content.

We are not pretty sure if there is something missing on the S3 server or if this is failling on frontend.

Any thoughts?

[image]

`<audio controls src="...s3.amazonaws.com/media/audio/filename.wav" />`